# Embedding excel sheet in Java Swing using Apache POI

Tags: java, swing, apache-poi

I was wondering if I could embed spreadsheet functionality in to Swing Components like the JInternalFrame using Apache POI. Is that possible at all? In the end I would like to read and edit the cells from within the application.

I know there is a commercial library JExcel which can do it. I could't find if Apache POI can do that. If it`s possible, maybe directing me to a sample or a brief explanation on how to go about it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Apache POI is an API designed to read and write various MS Office file formats, it's not designed to present them

Comment: You could parse the data via Apache POI, and then insert the data via a JTable

Comment: I want to have the user edit numerical values, insert cells, delete cells. etc. It would be much easier with some kind of spreadsheet functionality. I have used tables in the past, it is just bit cumbersome.

Comment: Have you tried the [Open Java Spreadsheet](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_swingsheet/downloads/openspreadsheet-0.1.jar/) or [OpenXLS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openxls/)  or [Jxcell](http://www.jxcell.net/)?

Comment: Let me check it out and get back.